# ¿Como puedo hacer para que la imagen principal sea reemplazada por una de la galeria?

Tags: javascript, php, html, imagen

tengo un producto con galeria con imagenes traida de la base de datos, en el foreach si el producto contiene imagenes mayores a 1, muestra una galeria con 6 imagenes traidas de la base de datos.

```
 <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="sh-ficha-galeryBox">
                <div class="sh-ficha-galery">
                    <ul class="sh-ficha-galery-list">
                        <?PHP
                        foreach ($galery as $key => $g) {
                            if (($key != 1) and ($g)) {
                        ?>
                                <li class=""><a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?= $g ?>"><img name='imgGalery' src="<?= $g; ?> " onclick="setSrc('imagMain', galery.src)" class="img-responsive center-block"></a></li>
                        <?PHP
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
            <div class="sh-ficha-mainPic">
                <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?= $galery[1] ?>"><img name='imgMain' src="<?= $galery[1]; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block" style="border-radius: 5px;"></a>

                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        function $($galery)
                        {
                            return document.getElementsByName('imgMain');
                        }
                        function setSrc(name, src)
                        {
                            var galery = document.getElementsByName('imgGalery');
                            galery.src = src;
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que se muestra en el navegador es una imagen principal(1) y al costado las otras 5. Yo quisiera que al hacer clic en alguna de esas otras 5, reemplacen a la principal y a su vez la principal pase a formar parte de las 5.

Comment: Primero y ante todo, reemplaza la imagen de código por texto plano, algo que se pueda copiar y así intentar darte ayuda sin tener que picar todo. Segundo, hay varias formas de hacer lo que pides, una opción es cambiar el src de la imagen principal por la que se ha hecho click, la otra, por ejemplo, sería tener todas las imagenes cargadas en un cuadro exactamente igual a la principal pero ocultas y mostrar una u otra según convenga... hay varias formas más.

Comment: Ahi subi el texto plano del codigo, con la img principal en el div class="sh-ficha-mainPic"

Comment: Creo que hacerlo "a mano" y "desde cero" no sería una opción muy adecuada. Te sugiero buscar algún script de galería o slider, seguramente ya existe algo como lo que quieres hacer o, tal vez, podrías encontrar otro que te guste más.

Comment: Claro, el tema es que ya esta setteado asi en el landindpage de mi trabajo, por eso tengo quiero aportar esa dinamica

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: Trate de agregar este script pero tampoco me funciona

<script type="text/javascript">

                            function $($galery)
                            {
                                return document.getElementsByName('imgMain');
                            }
                            function setSrc(name, src)
                            {
                                var galery = document.getElementsByName('imgGalery');
                                galery.src = src;
                            }
                        </script>

Comment: Edite el codigo arriba tratando de agregar ese script, y el evento onclick, pero no me funciona